# Display multiple annotations callout automatically in Swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

Is there a way to display multiple annotations callout at the same time?
I know how to display single annotation callout using `mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)` but couldn't able to display multiple callouts.

I tried to put `NSArray` of annotations but its throwing an error like `NSArray doesn't confirm to protocol MKAnnotation`.

Comment: I do work on it with the sample code of Apples WWDC 2017 - 237. You could have also a look on the WWDC 2015 - 206. Here are the links to it: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/206/